# Removing objects from superview by clicking on subviews

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, subview, cgrect

I have a `UIViewController` which places it's view on the screen and when it loads it creates an array of `CGRects`. It then adds those CGRects onto its view as subviews by filling them with a `UIView`.

I then create another `CGRect` and place it within one of these subviews and fill it with a `UIImageView`. It's set up to use `CGRectContainsPoint` and if the point is within one of the `UIView` `CGRects` it passes data to that object saying that it is there.

I can then click the `UIView` and it will use handleTap: to remove the origin point of the `UIImageView` rect from the super view.

Now the problem, I recently implemented a `NSTimer` and have it dropping new UIImageViews in at certain times. I also used the `CGRectContainsPoint` for loop to iterate through the array of UIView rectangles to check for `UIImageView` rectangles within them every one second.

When I run the program, I can click to remove the initial one, but when I click another it may or may not remove itself, I don't know why. However, sometimes when I click the first ones blank square it will remove one of the other ones and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not so sure about your problem. But i guess that you want to creat a view and when u click it ,it will be disappeared itself? And u try to add many of this views but it doesnt work directly u think.
See if i can help. you can creat a news class extends to UIView and add an tapGesture to it, which will refer to a method -(void)removeItSelf:(id)sender;

```
-(void)removeItself:(id)sender
{
   [self removeFromSuperView];

}
```

and create any instance of this view, it will be removed no metter how many u create.